# Connect flash where is the session object from

Tags: express, connect-flash

I am using in my express app the message alert middleware connect-flash. I can find this middleware on github https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-flash.
When i look at connect-flash source code, i really don't know, where the this.session object come from. Consider the connect-flash source code:

```
module.exports = function flash(options) {
  options = options || {};
  var safe = (options.unsafe === undefined) ? true : !options.unsafe;

  return function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.flash && safe) { return next(); }
    req.flash = _flash;
    next();
  }
}

function _flash(type, msg) {
  if (this.session === undefined) throw Error('req.flash() requires sessions');
  var msgs = this.session.flash = this.session.flash || {};
  if (type && msg) {
    // util.format is available in Node.js 0.6+
    if (arguments.length > 2 && format) {
      var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
      msg = format.apply(undefined, args);
    } else if (isArray(msg)) {
      msg.forEach(function(val){
        (msgs[type] = msgs[type] || []).push(val);
      });
      return msgs[type].length;
    }
    return (msgs[type] = msgs[type] || []).push(msg);
  } else if (type) {
    var arr = msgs[type];
    delete msgs[type];
    return arr || [];
  } else {
    this.session.flash = {};
    return msgs;
  }
}
```

To implement in express, i have to include within the app.configure block. Consider the code

```
app.configure(function () {
        //Other middleware
        app.use(function (req, res, next) {
            console.log(this.session);
            next();
        });
        app.use(flash());
```

Look at my custom middleware, when i display this.session object, i got "undefined". Why is this.session in connect-flash working, i get overthere the session object, but not in my middleware. The callback pattern for create a middleware are exactly the same

```
(function (req, res, next) {
        //Code
         next();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The session object is added by the session middleware. If `req.session` is undefined you either don't have the session middleware defined or you defined it after the middleware where you are expecting it.

Defined

- session middleware
- custom middleware: req.session is defined

Undefined

- custom middleware: req.session is undefined because the object gets added later.
- session middleware

So my guess is that you defined the flash middleware after `express.session` but your custom middleware is defined before `express.session`.

Since express is just an array of functions (middleware) that does stuff to the request and returns a response means that the order in which you define those functions matters.